# Where can I get CiA 302, CiA 304 and CiA 305?

Tags: can

Where do I find the following [CANopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) documents?

- CiA 302
- CiA 304
- CiA 305

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May or may not be :

305
http://www.elmomc.com/support/manuals/MAN-CAN305IG.pdf

304 online
http://www.softing.com/home/en/industrial-automation/products/can-bus/more-can-open/framework-dsp-304.php?navanchor=3010660

Maybe here - free signin
http://www.softing.com/home/en/industrial-automation/downloads/drivers-demos.php?T=4&G=2&P=1

Comment: Please advise if these were what was sought.

Comment: Even thought it's not exactly what I'm looking for, there's a lot of info there. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The CAN in Automation website has all the CANopen sepcifications.

http://www.can-cia.org/

However the specifications you require are in the members only section, and to access that you need to pay an annual subscription, which I think is about £3k

Comment: Makes one wonder what the "open" in CANopen is really supposed to mean.

Comment: The CiA is a non-profit organisation, however, the engineers still have to get paid! Its open in the sense of the basic specs are available to all, but if you want to do anything outside of this then you need the specs, especially if you are selling equipment as 'CANopen compliant'.  For the hobbyist its not really practical.

Comment: Plenty of the specs are available for free [from CIA](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=specifications&no_cache=1) if you just fill in some form. Been quite a while since I ordered the documents myself, but back in the days you could just buy all the specs on a CD without being a CIA member. It certainly didn't cost £3k. As for the case of CIA 304 it is apparently an EN standard nowadays, meaning you should be able to buy it from a standard institute.

Comment: Regarding "selling as CANopen compliant", you would want to have CIA act as 3rd party test house and guarantee conformance. After that, your product can be sold as certified for CANopen and it will appear on the [list of all certified devices](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=143).

Answer (score 3):

can-cia.org will supply specifications by email to non-members, membership allows you to directly download them from the site. I can't seem to see Cia302, or Cia304, but Cia305 is here: http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=915&no_cache=1

Answer (score 2):

Update for current status as some of the comments didnt match up with my research.

1. You can get any of the docs that are in public status by registering (eg full 301 spec) for free.
2. You can buy a series of docs for a one time fee that are in Draft Standard status (depends on series, ~512 euro for all 3xx DS), [link here](https://www.can-cia.org/groups/specifications/sale/)
3. If you want DSP specs, you have to become a paying member (i.e. 402, 305, etc), list of all docs [here](https://www.can-cia.org/groups/specifications/).  [Membership prices](https://www.can-cia.org/fileadmin/resources/documents/membership_application_2019.pdf) are annual and based off company size, but its currently ~3800 euro for a company less than 1k people.
4. One additional thing I found recently, some of the specs that are not public are standardized through IEC (ex DSP402 --> [IEC 61800-7-201](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/23753)).  So one additional resource for finding specs that may make more sense than becoming a full fledge CiA member if you just need a single spec.